# Share screen window to raspberry pi via LAN

Tags: multiple-monitors, raspberry-pi, vnc

I use a raspberry pi connected to a projector in another room over LAN. I usually just connect to it using VNC viewer and use it remotely / or run KODI. But I have come across a problem, sometimes I want to project apps that don't work on raspberry pi, and I cant use something like "ScreenTast" since it just mirrors the screen. I want to be able to use my PC while the app/"browser window" is being projected. So to get around the issue I use discord on raspberry but the latency and bit rate are terrible.

Are there any apps that allow local "app screen sharing" so I don't need to relay on external internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have  you ever tried OBS studio? It's free, and has many ways to redirect stream. You can choose IP, typical media to share, and edit a lot of parameters. The only thing you need to think is performance and encoding, because it takes maybe too many resources.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, after some browsing i found a way to turn the raspberry into a RTMP sever which should work.

Comment: Works like a charm, it does have about 3s delay but for my application this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using for your PC?

If Linux, `x11vnc -id pick` will run a VNC server showing only the application you click on (see `x11vnc` man page for more details on how to use it).

If Windows, `TightVNC` appears to be able to do this (see: https://www.tightvnc.com/release-2.7.php)

I'm not sure what happens if the application that you're sharing to the RaspberryPi is backgrounded on the PC, but it's likely that it won't share correctly (will either stop updating or will be overlaid by the foreground app).

Comment: I am using windows so TightVNC is a option, will try it out.